# FiddlerCore replace images without waiting to onBeforeResponse

Tags: c#, fiddlercore

Is there a way of replacing an image content with another without waiting for onBeforeResponse?

Right now I'm using:

onBeforeRequest:

```
if (oSession.fullUrl.IndexOf(".png") > -1) {
    oSession.fullUrl = "http://localhost/min.png";
}
```

onBeforeResponse:

```
if (oSession.fullUrl.IndexOf("http://localhost/") == 0)
{
    oSession.LoadResponseFromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + oSession.fullUrl.Substring(17));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
oSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
oSession.LoadResponseFromFile(FilePath);
```